# Validate That No Duplicates in Nested Relation - CakePHP 2

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

I need to make sure that there are no duplicates in a nested relationship. For instance, say I have a purchase that can have many purchase items. I want to make sure that there can't be more than 1 of the same purchase item.

The post data looks like this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to validate that purchase items are unique.

*The "isUnique" rule only checks that it is not already in the database, but does not check if there are two within the same post.*

**Note** that I have Purchase, PurchaseItem, and Item models. I am not sure which one the validation should really be in...

**Something I've tried, but doesn't work:**

```
// PurchaseItem model
public $validate = array(
    'item_id' => array(
        'unique' => array(
            'rule' => array('isUnique', array('purchase_id', 'item_id'), false),
            'message' => 'You may only use the same item once!'
        )
    )
);
```

**Q** What is the best way to validate in this situation?

Comment: I know it's old, but I don't see purchase_id in your request. If you are on insert mode (create) and you don't know purchase_id yet, you'll need to add an extra hidden field: PurchaseItem.KEY.something = 'same value' and try to validate item_id with `'rule' => array('isUnique', array('something', 'item_id'), false)`

Answer (score 0):

You won't (as far as I am aware) be able to validate the `hasMany` data like this using Cake's validator. Validation is called for each individual record being saved rather than for all the data as a whole. So you won't be able to just write a custom validation rule for your model.

When Cake saves `hasMany` data what it does is call `$this->Model->save()` for each record; this is where validation gets called along with the `beforeSave` and `beforeValidate` callbacks. They can only see the data for the individual record getting saved.

Instead you will need to take a more manual approach to validating just before saving. You could do this by extending `saveMany()` for your model:-

```
public function saveMany($data = null, $options = array()) {
    // 1. Do some additional cross record validation here 
    //    (return false if duplicates found)
    // 2. Continue to save
    return parent::saveMany($data, $options);
}
```

You could perhaps [add a new callback](http://andy-carter.com/blog/cakephp-aftersaveall-callback) for `beforeSaveMany` and add your extra validation rules in the new callback.

If you find that the data contains duplicates you can use Cake's Validator to flag the relevant field as an issue should you want:-

```
$this->Model->invalidate('field_name', 'error message');
```

To test the data (which I assume you only want to test is unique in the submitted data and not in the database) you could utilise [Cake's Hash utility](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html). It should be simple to extract the data you want and check for duplicates.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll give your ideas a shot and see how they work.

Comment: In which model are you implying that your piece of code should go?

Comment: Hi @karns, assuming you're saving from the `Purchase` (*i.e.* `$this->Purchase->saveAssociated($this->request->data);`) then you probably want to put the logic in that model. I've just reread your original question and it sounds like you want to check that no purchase contains multiples of a particular item. In that case I would probably write a method for adding items to a purchase in my `Purchase` model and call that method to save new items to the purchase. Then in that method I would run my custom validation before saving the data. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just to check. Are you wanting the ability to have one record representing multiple quantities, and that duplicate items are merged into one record with the appropriate quantity?

Comment: For lack of time, I ended up just looping through the request data in the controller and checking a hash for dups and setting a flash error message. I really don't like this solution :/ However, I'd still like to figure out a better way. 

To answer your Q, no - I do not want to merge duplicate quantities. I simply want to invalidate the submission.